# How can I restrict a number input between 1 to 12 in Kendo Grid Inline Editing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid and one column should expect a number between 0 to 12. Everything else are working fine except HourTimeHours. I can't put min value smaller than 0 but i can put more than 12 for that. please help.

```
schema: {
            model: {
                id: "ID",
                fields: {
                    ID: { editable: false },
                    TName: { editable: false },
                    HourTimeHours: { editable: true, type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 0, max: 12 } },
                    Comment: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                    Reason: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    ChargeRateText: { defaultValue: { CategoryID: "No Charge", CategoryName: "No Charge" } },
                }
            },
```

Comment: Can you show us your grid creation code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to specify an editor for that field when creating your grid.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    columns: [
        { field: "HourTimeHours", title: "Hours", editor: hoursDropDownEditor }],
    editable: true
});
```

And then if you want something like a kendo numeric text box, your function will look something like this:

```
function hoursDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoNumericTextBox({
            min: 1,
            max: 12,
            step: 1
    });
}
```

**Update:** You could also use a template, which makes it clear to the user that the field is editable.

http://jsfiddle.net/amomsen/vcpWD/1/

Comment: have to add the field of the name from the options though, e.g. `$('<input  name="'+options.field+'"/>')`, else no update will take place (will not take the value)

Answer (score 0):

For Kendo UI MVC you can restrict length of Kendo Grid Inline Editing

```
    $("body").delegate("#percentage", "keyup", function () { 
        $("#percentage").attr('maxlength', '5');
    });
```

Where #percentage is id of cell to Edit

```
columns.Bound(p => p.percentage);
```

All grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Internal.Models.ExchangeRateData>()
    .Name("ExchangeGrid") 
    .Columns(columns =>
    { 
        columns.Bound(p => p.targetCurrency);
        columns.Bound(p => p.percentage);
        columns.Command(commands => { commands.Edit(); }); 
    }) 
    .Editable(edit =>
    {
        edit.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine); 
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(item => item.targetCurrency);  
        }) 
        .Events(events =>
        {
            events.Sync("onSync");
        })
        .Read(read => read.Action("ExchangeRate_Read", "ExchangeRatesFortius").Data("ReadRequestData"))
        .Update(c => c.Action("Currencies_Update", "ExchangeRatesFortius")) 
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For kendo mvc, i was able to limit with a template as such:

```
 columns.Bound(m => m.Inches)
                .ClientTemplate("<input type=\"number\" value=#= Inches # min=\"0\" max=\"11\" step=\"1\" ></input>")
                .Width(60);
```